# How replace € from string

Tags: php, replace

How could replace a € from string with PHP.

I have a lot of variables with € and cant replace them.

Y try:

```
$var = "€ 66 ";

$change = str_replace("€","",$var);
```

But this don't change nothing.

Edit: can't replace with str_replace.

See the code:

```
foreach ($city as $citi) {
    $cinti = $citi;
    $as = str_replace('€ ', '', $cinti);

   var_dump($as);

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Then i get this:

```
string(4) "€ 50" 
string(4) "€ 65" 
string(4) "€ 65" 
string(5) "€ 141" 
string(4) "€ 75" 
string(5) "€ 165"
```

RESULT:

At least, i can't make it properly, so i get only the numbers and continue with my things...

```
foreach ($city as $citi) {

    $ss = $citi[0];
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ss, $matches);

     echo $matches[0][0].','.$citi[1];

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/MU04H

Comment: @Maion can't with str_replace.

I try with the function but is imposible.

Comment: I don't see where your problem is nor can I reproduce it

Comment: @rizier123 i put my code to see and the result.

Comment: `$as = $cinti[0];` You overwrite your converted array again! Do: `$as = $as[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source file character encoding is UTF-8 then € is a multibyte char. str_replace only works for ISO-8859-1 / Latin1 strings properly.

Try something like this:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");

$city = array( "€ 50","€ 65","€ 65");

foreach ($city as $citi) {
    $as = mb_eregi_replace('€','',$citi);
    var_dump($as); 
    echo '<br>';
}
```

I updated the example to better suit the example code of yours.

Output:

```
string(3) " 50" 
string(3) " 65" 
string(3) " 65"
```

You may add a trim() to get rid of the whitespace.

Comment: ` $ss = $citi[0];
    $a = mb_eregi_replace('€','',$ss);
     var_dump($a);`
Still don't go.

Comment: In your example in the original post your var_dump uses a $as variable that was overwritten by $as=$cinti[0]; Therefore what str_replace does is irrelevant. Maybe you can provide a full example including the $city Array to set what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$var = "€ 66 ";
$change = str_replace("&euro;", "", htmlentities(trim($var)));

echo $change;
```